# Creating NSOpenGLView inside an NSDocument (OS X)

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, nsdocument, nsopenglview

I am creating a music-eduaction app that reads in musical scores - not audio files - and will need to present an animated graphical screen. I created a document-based app to make file access easy, and I have it now reading and parsing the files, and I have all the song data stored in my Obj-C classes. I also have a textview in my xib that I can write song attributes and other text tidbits to. Now I want a second view, which needs to be graphical and animatable, for the music. I am an Xcode novice, but have some openGL experience. My setup is latest OS and Xcode versions.

When I try to drag the OpenGL View into my window in IB, I get a weird error/warning that says "Unsupported Configuration - NSOpenGLView in One Shot memory enabled window" (so that is weird), and the openGL view does not appear when I run the app.

I can't find much reference to OpenGL Views in NSdocuments on this site, or anywhere else, which makes me think I might be trying to do something that is not meant to be done. Does anyone have any advice for me? Should I not use a document-based app? Should I use something other than openGL? Or maybe I need to build the openGL View and View Controller 100% programmatically in this case? Any advice or pointers to some applicable samples/tutorials would be a huge help.

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling the "One Shot" option from the Windows's memory attributes in Interface Builder.

From NSWindow documentation:

> setOneShot: Sets whether the window device that the window manages
> should be freed when it’s removed from the screen list.
>
> `- (void)setOneShot:(BOOL)oneShot`
>
> Parameters
>
> oneShot YES to free the window’s window device when it’s removed from the screen list (hidden)
> and to create another one when it’s returned to the screen; NO to
> reuse the window device.
>
> Discussion
>
> Freeing the window device when
> it’s removed from the screen list can result in memory savings and
> performance improvement for NSWindow objects that don’t take long to
> display. It’s particularly appropriate for NSWindow objects the user
> might use once or twice but not display continually.